# VisualForce Page works perfectly in SandBox Preview but doesn't even appear in production

Tags: visualforce, sandbox

Why is this occuring? I'm trying to add a HelpScout beacon to a Home Page Layout by creating a custom VF Page componenent. Not even my HTML text will appear. Here's the apex code:
[image: Apex Code]

Comment: Did you add it to your layout? Does the component have sufficient height? Does the profile have security access to the page? What have you checked so far? Do you see any errors on the Developer Console (F12)?

Comment: Added to the layout. Tested all heights and tested with/without scrolling. Yes, security was set to the appropriate profiles. No compiler errors.